# How to Fill the Surface I Have on this Sphere?

Tags: tikz-pgf, geometry

I have this sphere with manually draw surface (with arc), very beginner method.

I want to fill it with color, tell me how like this:

[image: 1]

my MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \shade[ball color = gray!40, opacity = 0.4] (0,0) circle (2cm);
        \draw (0,0) circle (2cm);
        \draw (-2,0) arc (180:360:2 and 0.6);
        \draw[dashed] (2,0) arc (0:180:2 and 0.6);
        \fill[fill=black] (0,0) circle (1pt);
        \draw (0.71,1.67) arc (180:225:2.5 and 0.8);
        \draw (0,0 ) -- node[above]{$r$} (0.8,1.83);
        \draw (0,0 ) -- node[above]{$r$} (1.6,1.2);
        \draw (0,0 ) -- node[above]{$r$} (2,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: 2]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{hobby}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[use Hobby shortcut]
\draw[dashed] (2,0) arc[start angle=0, end angle=180, radius=2, y radius=0.6];
\shadedraw[ball color=blue!40, fill opacity=0.4] (0,0) circle[radius=2];
\draw (-2,0) arc[start angle=180, end angle=360, radius=2, y radius=0.6];
\fill (0,0) circle[radius=1pt];
\draw (0,0) -- node[above, pos=0.6]{$r$} (2,0);
\draw[dashed] (0,0) -- (40:1.6);
\draw[dashed] (0,0) -- (70:1.6);
\clip[closed] (40:1.6) .. (50:1.45) .. (70:1.6) .. (60:1.85);
\shade[ball color=blue!40, fill opacity=0.3] (0,0) circle[radius=2];
\draw[thick, closed] (40:1.6) .. (50:1.45) .. (70:1.6) .. (60:1.85);
\node[font=\small] at (55:1.65) {S};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Shaded ball with marked surface area]

Comment: Simpler: `\draw[fill=blue, thick, closed] (40:1.6) .. (50:1.45) .. (70:1.6) .. (60:1.85);` -but without the correct tones of shading.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
%% Compile and read me!
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}
% Gradient Info
  
\tikzset {_k6mv1ejnm/.code = {\pgfsetadditionalshadetransform{ \pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{0 bp } { 0 bp }  }  \pgftransformrotate{0 }  \pgftransformscale{2 }  }}}
\pgfdeclarehorizontalshading{_z1ak5ajdj}{150bp}{rgb(0bp)=(0.71,0.96,0.96);
rgb(37.5bp)=(0.71,0.96,0.96);
rgb(62.5bp)=(0.66,0.92,0.99);
rgb(100bp)=(0.66,0.92,0.99)}
\tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=0.75pt}} %set default line width to 0.75pt        

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=-1,xscale=1]
%uncomment if require: \path (0,477); %set diagram left start at 0, and has height of 477

%Shape: Circle [id:dp4105016822718395] 
\path  [shading=_z1ak5ajdj,_k6mv1ejnm] (180,221.9) .. controls (180,153.47) and (235.47,98) .. (303.9,98) .. controls (372.33,98) and (427.8,153.47) .. (427.8,221.9) .. controls (427.8,290.33) and (372.33,345.8) .. (303.9,345.8) .. controls (235.47,345.8) and (180,290.33) .. (180,221.9) -- cycle ; % for fading 
 \draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 251; green, 253; blue, 254 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=1.5]  (180,221.9) .. controls (180,153.47) and (235.47,98) .. (303.9,98) .. controls (372.33,98) and (427.8,153.47) .. (427.8,221.9) .. controls (427.8,290.33) and (372.33,345.8) .. (303.9,345.8) .. controls (235.47,345.8) and (180,290.33) .. (180,221.9) -- cycle ; % for border 

%Straight Lines [id:da24551258669086784] 
\draw [color={rgb, 255:red, 149; green, 208; blue, 225 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=1.5]    (303.9,221.9) -- (427.08,220.01) ;
%Straight Lines [id:da8242464718458027] 
\draw [color={rgb, 255:red, 149; green, 208; blue, 225 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=1.5]    (303.9,221.9) -- (355.8,161) ;
%Straight Lines [id:da009573593426575266] 
\draw [color={rgb, 255:red, 149; green, 208; blue, 225 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=1.5]    (320.8,121) -- (299.4,221.9) ;
%Shape: Arc [id:dp14552988688203028] 
\draw  [draw opacity=0][line width=1.5]  (180,222.01) .. controls (180.41,231.62) and (235.57,239.4) .. (303.54,239.4) .. controls (366.61,239.4) and (418.63,232.71) .. (426.15,224.06) -- (303.54,221.9) -- cycle ; \draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 152; green, 202; blue, 217 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=1.5]  (180,222.01) .. controls (180.41,231.62) and (235.57,239.4) .. (303.54,239.4) .. controls (366.61,239.4) and (418.63,232.71) .. (426.15,224.06) ;  
%Shape: Arc [id:dp5555036816617602] 
\draw  [draw opacity=0][dash pattern={on 5.63pt off 4.5pt}][line width=1.5]  (427.08,220.01) .. controls (420.4,211.23) and (367.8,204.4) .. (303.9,204.4) .. controls (235.73,204.4) and (180.41,212.18) .. (180,221.79) -- (303.9,221.9) -- cycle ; \draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 152; green, 202; blue, 217 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][dash pattern={on 5.63pt off 4.5pt}][line width=1.5]  (427.08,220.01) .. controls (420.4,211.23) and (367.8,204.4) .. (303.9,204.4) .. controls (235.73,204.4) and (180.41,212.18) .. (180,221.79) ;  
%Shape: Polygon Curved [id:ds004137480371948721] 
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 149; green, 208; blue, 225 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][fill={rgb, 255:red, 226; green, 244; blue, 253 }  ,fill opacity=1 ][line width=1.5]  (355.8,161) .. controls (359.8,141) and (372.8,128) .. (333.8,118) .. controls (294.8,108) and (351.8,181) .. (355.8,161) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Circle [id:dp2446912683584801] 
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 7; green, 173; blue, 237 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][fill={rgb, 255:red, 7; green, 173; blue, 237 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (297.4,221.9) .. controls (297.4,219.41) and (299.41,217.4) .. (301.9,217.4) .. controls (304.39,217.4) and (306.4,219.41) .. (306.4,221.9) .. controls (306.4,224.39) and (304.39,226.4) .. (301.9,226.4) .. controls (299.41,226.4) and (297.4,224.39) .. (297.4,221.9) -- cycle ;

% Text Node
\draw (291,169.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$r$};
% Text Node
\draw (343,174.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$r$};
% Text Node
\draw (343,225) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$r$};
% Text Node
\draw (339,128.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$S$};


\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```